# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in 'react-cerbos-demo/node_modules/cerbos'

Tags: reactjs, npm, process, cerbos

I tried all answers none of them are working.

Here is https://codesandbox.io/p/github/AvinashDalvi89/react-cerbos-demo code playground is available.

https://github.com/AvinashDalvi89/react-cerbos-demo